# Python df Split String based on multiple Separators and search the patterns further to populate columns

Tags: regex, pandas

I am trying to ask the below a bit more concisely, so I can understand your solutions and improvise from there.
I have a df with certain columns plus a column named ROLES that looks something like below:

```
COLA COLB COLC   ROLES
                 ABCD Walters Sr. (Actor), XYZ (Actor, Director), PQR Industries (Producer, Writer)
                 PQABC12 (Director), DGKJG (Actor), PQR (Producer), DJGHJDGH (Lead Role)
```

I want to split this ROLES column such that i fetch out the Actors for that row into another column named ACTORS, and the rest of the people can go into OTHER ROLES column.
So the
**Desired Output** would look like:

```
COLA COLB COLC   ACTORS       OTHER ROLES
                 ABCD, XYZ    XYZ,PQR
                 DGKJG        PQABC12, PQR, DJGHJDGH
```

My approach was to first split the ROLES column into a list containing elements for each entity/person. And then traverse the list to fetch the element that contains Actor.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
df = df.assign(ROLES=df['ROLES'].str.split(",\s*(?![^()]*\))")).explode('ROLES')
df['Type'] = np.where(df['ROLES'].str.contains('Actor'),'Actor','Other Roles')
newdf = df.groupby('Type').agg({'ROLES':lambda x: ','.join(x)}).reset_index()
newdf = newdf.set_index('Type').T
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode' Tried upgrading pandas, importing it again, but still getting this attribute error

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: the statement without explode works well.
Will have to find alternative of explode

Comment: df['ACTOR'] = df.apply(
        lambda elem: [elem for elem in df['Roles'].str if "Actor" in elem],
    axis=1)

What if i use this ?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 23: expected str instance, float found (I get this in the .agg .join statement

Comment: Can you help how the groupby statement is working here ?

Comment: It is grouping by Type, and then it is aggregating all the ROLES (which are text) and adding a comma in between. I think you might have a number in roles instead of a string if you are getting a float error. You can try adding `str(x)` in the join function (so it would be `',',join(str(x))`

Comment: SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported